Scraping and input via Firefox Input does not work
Good day friends,
I am trying to trigger a search on the Calculator website. I would like to do this automatically on my Raspberry Pi. Everything works fine on my laptop with the Chrome browser:
https://sellercentral.amazon.de/hz/fba/profitabilitycalculator/
# Warte auf den Gast-Button und klicke darauf
guest_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//kat-button[@label='Als Gast fortfahren']"))
)
guest_button.click()

# Länderauswahl
dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//kat-dropdown[@label='Amazon Shop']"))
)
dropdown.click()
de_option = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//kat-option[@value='DE']"))
)
de_option.click()

# Suche nach der ASIN
print(f"Bearbeite ASIN {asin}...")
search_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//kat-input[@label='Bei Amazon nach dem Produkt suchen']"))
)

# JavaScript verwenden, um den Wert des Eingabefeldes zu leeren
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '';", search_input)
search_input.send_keys(asin)
search_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

However, I have to use Firefox on the Raspberry Pi. When I try it with this browser, the element can no longer be found. The country selector still works and I click on ‘Continue as guest’, but the input no longer works.
I get the following error:
Bearbeite ASIN B08GM8JQX2...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <kat-input class="input-asin" type="text"> is not reachable by keyboard
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:193:5
ElementNotInteractableError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:353:5
webdriverSendKeysToElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/interaction.sys.mjs:669:13
interaction.sendKeysToElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/interaction.sys.mjs:641:11
sendKeysToElement@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.sys.mjs:523:29
receiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsChild.sys.mjs:151:31

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can solve this problem? I would be grateful for any help!
Many thanks in advance!
I have already tried all possibilities, whether with xpath CSS or similar, but unfortunately nothing works.
